# for loop until button is pressed in Android?

Tags: android, csv

I am new to Android. How can I run this For loop until the button is pressed? I am writing saved data of array into CSV file and storing it onto SDcard. I want to keep the loop running until I press `writeFileBtn` and it saves the data into CSV.

```
import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button getTimeBtn, writeFileBtn;
    ArrayList<String> entries;

    String[] entriesArr;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        entries = new ArrayList<String>();

        getTimeBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.get_time);

        writeFileBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.write_file);

        getTimeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                    entries.add(String.valueOf(System.nanoTime()));

                    entriesArr = entries.toArray(new String[entries.size()]);
                }
            }
        });

        writeFileBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                CSVWriter writer = null;
                try 
                {
                    writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) + "myfile.csv"), ',');
                    //String[] entries = "first#second#third".split("#"); // array of your values
                    writer.writeNext(entriesArr);  
                    writer.close();
                } 
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: short answer ... you need new Thread ... basically in run() of thread `{while(running){ /*loop here*/} /* write file here*/ }` ... then in on click of first button you starting the thread ... and in second set `running` to false ...

Comment: of course it is just POC and have some caveats ... the real implementation should take to an account that activity can be closed ... or recreated ... so it would be better to use fx service ..... etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an AsyncTask to do this work on background.

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     int count = urls.length;
     long totalSize = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
         publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
         // Escape early if cancel() is called
         if (isCancelled()) break;
     }
     return totalSize;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
 }
```

}

AsynkTask provides you a isCancelled() that can be used by your button.

Comment: The problem is I am really new to this coding. I have tried many solutions but not successful so far. Can somebody help me in modification my code already mentioned above?

Comment: you mean: writing the code for you, for free? why? josealfonsomora's example should be enough